# Asset managers for Django - choose which one?

Tags: django, django-apps

I would like to bundle up css and javascript files. I also want to send far-future expire headers to clients, so I need file versioning.

A quick search across the Internet has shown there are several asset managers developed for Django. Here is a list of those that I could reach:

1. [django-compress](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/)
2. [django-assets](http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/django-assets/)
3. [django-assetpackager](http://code.google.com/p/django-assetpackager/)
4. [django-media-bundler](http://github.com/rnk/django-media-bundler)
5. [django-mediacat](http://github.com/zvoase/django-mediacat)
6. [django-site-assets](http://github.com/foxbunny/django-site-assets)
7. [django-static-management](http://github.com/bradleywright/django-static-management)
8. [django-compressor](http://github.com/mintchaos/django_compressor)

They seem to perform more or less the same job. django-compress, django-compressor and django-site-assets seem to be especially promising at the first glance. I will appreciate if someone provides feedback on any of them that will help me choose between them.

Comment: If you're looking to be exhaustive, you might also want to include django-compressor. http://github.com/mintchaos/django_compressor

Comment: In 2011 the top 3 has changed significantly I think, djangoplugables.com has a nice feature chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the contenders I have chosen **django-compressor** because it is incredibly simple to use. Just put one or two tags (typical scenario: one for css and another for js) in the template and for most cases you are done without modifying anything; you don't even have to declare or modify settings, its default settings are good.

Answer (score 11):

As you have already noticed, they all do the same thing (more or less). I decided to go ahead with [django_compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor).

Also, I prefer to set **expire headers** or apply on-the-fly **compression** at the *web server level*. IMHO these operations should not be performed by the application itself, because sometimes it can lead to some issues, for instance setting *Cache-Control* or expiration headers on error pages etc. The *mod_expires* module is very [easy to configure](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) according to your needs. For on-the-fly compression using the DEFLATE output filter, I have used this [mod_deflate configuration](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/05/10/use-mod_deflate-to-compress-web-content-delivered-by-apache/) as is.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I followed your choice and I can say django-compressor is incredibly easy to use. Regarding the other issue you mentioned, I have already been setting expire headers and gzipping images at the web server level (lighttpd is the choice), I'll just add css and js to the file types.

Comment: Gzipping images is a bad bad idea. At best, it's just increasing server load, at worse, it might actually increase the images file size.

Answer (score 7):

New projects have been created since this question was asked.

You might want to take a look at [django-pipeline](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline), it's pretty nifty.

Comment: Thank you for updating this SO thread.  django_compressor/"Compressor" w/ django 1.4 has been a nightmare.

Comment: Is very nice and has also python3 support

Answer (score 4):

I've been using django-compress and I'm happy with it, especially because I can specify the back-end compressor (YUI works best with my JS for example).

I will probably consider switching to django_compressor in the future, but it's too low priority atm.

I would also point out that django-media-bundler has one feature the others don't... automatic building of image sprites.  I haven't used it live, so I'm not sure how well it is implemented but that's pretty neat.  You can use it just for the sprites and leave css/js for one of the other compressors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My to-do list includes using css sprites, and I may give django-media-bundler a shot when the time comes. But for the time being I have fallen for the simplicity of django-compressor ;)

Answer (score 2):

FWIW since djangopluggables.com doesn't exist anymore and nobody has mentioned it here yet: The most recent comparison is on [djangopackages.com](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/), where [django_compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor) is the most used one ATM. Haven't tried it with 1.4 though as Jay Taylor warned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684062/asset-managers-for-django-choose-which-one#comment16716514_9483586).